# How to manage states of a Asp.net web games

Tags: asp.net, cookies

Say I need to develop a online cheese games and the game is just between computer and a real human player.

The req is to keep states (like steps,win history) usable even after the user closing browsers or server temp being offline  in short time.  Thus when the player goes back to the game page, he should be keep playing from what he played last time, and get his play history as well.

It is definitely need  cookie to enable all this, but i m concerning about the security of using that. I should prevent ppl hacking the cookie directly to change the history or sth.  My thought is to make the server end assign a token to client. All the steps and history data are associated with this token string and stored in a persistent layer (database). Thus, a user have no idea to change the data in DB.

Is it a overdesign , or there is a way to encrypt cookies.

Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have alluded to, you have 2 choices:

1) **Encrypt the current state of the game and put it into a cookie**

This can definitely be done so that the client cannot modify the state, by using a encryption. You will however need to send a plain text version of the game state down to the client as well. When the client sends back their move, you would decrypt the cookie to get the last state, validate their move and modify the state. Rinse and repeat.

The downside of this is the increased traffic and the need to implement the de/encryption.

2) **Store the game state on the server and use a cookie as the user identifier (or a login system)**

This is probably the best solution as it will allow you to structure the data properly and reduce the amount of traffic to the user. You will just need to send the current state of the game down to the client. The client then just sends back their move. When you receive their move, you load the game from storage, validate the client made a valid mode, then adjust the state.

The downside is that you need to keep the state at your end for some time, either in a DB or a cache (Velocity?). Also consider a NoSQL solution for this perhaps.

Comment: `(1)` is not a good solution. You should *never* trust the client, and you can't guarantee the aforementioned client won't ever be able to tamper with the encrypted cookie, someday, somehow. Everything should be on the server. `(2)` is the way to go.

Comment: Sure, the client can tamper with it, but not in a way that it will continue to be able to be decrypted once it's sent back to the server. Since the client does not have the encryption key, they can't change the cookie and encrypt it in a way that the server can then decrypt. ASP.NET cookies/viewstate works like that. What's to stop the client messing with the session identifier used in 2)? They can, but it will get them nowhere.

Comment: Fixed up the answer to imply that symmetric encryption should be used, no need for asymetric (public/private). No keys are given to the client, so they can't change the state and encrypt a valid cookie.

Comment: (2) is exactly what i thought. go for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do.

1. Have the all the game logic done on the
   client side. Running an opponent AI on your server would be very costly.
2. Save the state using
   window.localStorage (perhaps have a
   fallback using ajax for older
   browsers)
3. Send off the steps to your server to validate the moves, log a win etc.

This isn't the only way and may not be the best for your situation.

Comment: thx, but i think local storage. Just like any other client side storage options this data can be viewed and modified by the user.

Comment: All data sent to and from the client will be either a) unusable or b) accessible and modifiable by the user. This includes cookies.

Comment: Right, that's the reason I want store a token in cookie, but store real data in DB. Then,if he changes token in cookie, then it will just turn to be a invalid token, no harm to the real data.

Answer (score 0):

Why not encrypt the cookie data?  You could use these extension methods to add an easy encrypt/decrypt method to the string class:
http://www.extensionmethod.net/Details.aspx?ID=69